# Missing row from output

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a small problem for which I don't find the answer.

I have a table called `product_features` with the following fields:

```
product_features
----------------------
 id  parent_id  name      order    added_date
```

Now the problem is that I've just inserted 2 rows having the same name:

```
734     1   6008-2 test     0   2012-11-21 11:52:28
735     1   6008-2 test     0   2012-11-21 11:57:27
```

I have defined `id - PRIMARY INDEX - AUTO INCREMENT` and `parent_id - INDEX`

```
Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column     Cardinality  Collation
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes      No product_feature_id  671         A       
product_feature_parent_id   BTREE   No  No  product_feature_parent_id   671 A
```

When I'm printing the results the only row which is printed is the last one.. and I really don't understand why. This is the function I'm using:

```
public function printProductFeaturesTable($product_feature_parent_id = 0, $level = 0){
        $sql = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT product_feature_id, product_feature_name
                                     FROM product_features
                                     WHERE product_feature_parent_id='" . $product_feature_parent_id . "'
                                     ORDER BY product_feature_order");
        if($sql->num_rows != 0) {

            if($level != 0)
                echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="dnd"><tbody>';

            $i = 0;
            while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
                $i++;
                echo '<tr>
                        <td width="30" valign="top" align="center">', 
                            $i, '.
                        </td>
                        <td>', 
                            $row['product_feature_name'],
                            '<div class="table-options">
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_feature_id[]" value="', $row['product_feature_id'], '" /> 
                                <a href="/admin/product-features/add-modify/', $row['product_feature_id'], '" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all left"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span></a>
                                <a href="javascript:if(confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this feature?\')) document.location = \'/admin/resources/php/product-features.php?p=delete&pfid=', $row['product_feature_id'], '\'" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all left"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></a>
                            </div>';

                $this->printProductFeaturesTable($row['product_feature_id'], $level + 1);

                echo '  </td>
                    </tr>'; 
            }

            if($level != 0)
                echo '</tbody></table>';
        } else
            if($product_feature_parent_id == 0)
                echo '<tr><td align="center" colspan="2">Nici o specificatie de produs adaugata momentan!</td></tr>';
    }
```

The result should be like this:

```
1. Test
   1. Test subcategory
   2. Test subcategory 2
   3. 6008-2 test
   4. 6008-2 test
```

but instead of the example above, the result is:

```
1. Test
   1. Test subcategory
   2. Test subcategory 2
   3. 6008-2 test // this is the last inserted row.. but where is the other one???
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Have you run your query directly against the database outside of your app? I suspect you'll find that this is a rendering issue and you are skipping that row in the output, for some reason - it looks like you might be skipping over this record because of the $level check.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. I've done this already and the results are the same :( `SELECT product_feature_id, product_feature_name
           FROM product_features
           WHERE product_feature_parent_id='1'
           ORDER BY product_feature_order`

Comment: is the parent_id column a varchar? if so, could it be that you have a space or another not visible char in one of the rows?

Comment: No it isn't.. `parent_id` is `bigint(20)`

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. I've just discovered that the only problem were my eyes, as you can see i'm ordering the results by `product_feature_order`, which in this example is 0 by default.

So the problem was that the order they are shows is not in the order of the inserted id, which really confused me..

Thank you for your time!